# Clojure File Response

Tags: file, clojure, upload, response

I am currently building a **Clojure** database-backed website on a **Luminus +h2** framework. I am *working on* **file uploading** currently, and *stuck* at the point of actually **retrieving the files.** Though I'm not completely sure this was the best way to approach the situation, *here is what I have done so far*:

I have a route that allows me to upload files. The files that get uploaded are copied to the /resources/public/Files folder inside of my project:

```
(io/copy actual-file (io/file "resources" "public" "Files" file-name))
```

Furthermore, I store the **file name** of each of the files inside of a database table that is created and manipulated using **SQL.**

I then have a new route which shows all of the files that have been uploaded as links (by accessing the database). In the back end, the links direct the page to a new route "/file/:file-name" in which the file-response function is called. I'm hoping that the links will work as "downloads" for the files.

As my *first attempt* at this working, I copied all the files to my C:/AllFiles folder, and did this:

```
(defn serve-file [file-name]
  (file-response (str (files-path) File/separator file-name)))
```

where files-path is:

```
(defn files-path [] "/AllFiles")
```

This actually was working for me. However, I want the file that I'm using to be the one from inside my specific project directory, without me having to type the whole path (i.e. so that it works for anyone using it, at ~/Project-Name/resources/public/Files").

For some reason, I can't seem to get file-response to work like such.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show us more of your code?

Comment: @lispHK01 such as what parts?

Comment: an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can. what error are you getting? (is this error being shown in the browser?) also, what do you mean when you say "without me having to type the whole path" ?

Comment: @lispHK01 I'm not getting an error. If I use this:
(defn files-path-2 [] "/Users/Me/Projects/Three/webdev/resources/public/Files")

(defn serve-file [file-name]
  (file-response (str (files-path-2) File/separator file-name)))

Then it works as I want it to. I would prefer not to have the files-path-2 written out like this, but rather a more direct, and non-specific to my own computer, pathway. I'm using "lein run" from the three/webdev root folder. I would like to know if there's a way to edit files-path-2 to be root/resources/public/Files instead, essentially.

Comment: ok it sounds like you need a way to modify your files-path variable at runtime, possibly based on the current working directory of the process?

Comment: @lispHK01 yes that sounds like a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so a couple ideas (i'm not sure what will suit your situation best):

- you can get the current working directory of the process like so:

`(System/getProperty "user.dir")`

- you can change the current working directory like so:

`(System/getProperty "user.dir" "/users/lispHK01")`

So you could potentially do something like this:

```
(def initial-working-path (System/getProperty "user.dir"))

(def my-relative-files-path "foo/bar/wherefileswillbe")

(def files-path
  (str
    initial-working-path
    File/separator
    my-relative-files-path))
```

If you are needing to update `files-path` multiple times, you can use an `atom` to do so (though, standard Clojure 'best practices' disclaimer: try to look for a functional/immutable approach prior to relying on an atom). An atom is derefed by prefacing with `@`, e.g.:

```
user=> (def foo (atom "my/path"))
#'user/foo
user=> @foo
"my/path"
user=> (reset! foo "my/new/path")
"my/new/path"
user=> @foo
"my/new/path"
user=>
```

Comment: Was just going to comment and say that it is System/getProperty -- I see you just edited it however. This worked perfectly for me, thanks a lot! Much appreicated